# how to fill an array in a loop with variables which are created in this loop (in php)?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, fill

I want to generate or fill an array in a loop with variables (in php). But these variables are written in this loop.

so an example:

```
$i = 1;
while(i<10){
    $a = array("$i","$i","$i");  
    i++;
}
```

the secound and the third i variables should be added in the next passage. So finaly the array will include the numbers from 0 to 10. I found something with $$variables but i don't thing there is a usefull usage.

What is a possible way for this? Thank you :)

Comment: close vote .. array basic usage: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: you are using $i and i.  I think they all should be $i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are stuck, that you don't know how to add an element to an array, which is something pretty basic.

Just add an element to your array every iteration like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 10) { //If you want 0 - 10 including 10, just change '=' to '<='
    $a[] = $i;  
    $i++;  //Assuming, that the missing dollar signs are typos, since you already did it right once
}
```

Read up more about arrays here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: thank you. That was so easy :D There my ignorance gets out. But thank you anyway

Comment: @Dagon Seems like New Zealand's internet takes a while :)

Comment: @Rizier123 its powered by sheep

Comment: @Dagon Then I think it's time again to feed them, so your internet speed's up.

Comment: 9am winter, they are cold, let them have their morning coffee and bacon and eggs and they will perk up

Comment: i have to wait 2 minutes. Then i will accept your help :)

Answer (score 3):

an alternative approach is to just use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$a=range(0,10);
```

Comment: Another funny method would be: `$i = 1; while(($b[] = $i++) < 10);` or just `for($i = 1; ($b[] = $i++) < 10;);` :)

Comment: @Rizier123 its php i can think of 32.5 ways to do it :-)